# codeigniter in subfolder

Tags: codeigniter, routes, subdirectory

I made a backoffice module using codeigniter for one of our websites and I've put it into a folder called **backoffice**. The website itself does not use any framework, its just a couple of static websites, some of them reading some data from database. It does not have any .htaccess file or any routing.

When I try to access the backoffice it does not work. The error log says it is trying to get my default controller from outside of the subfoler:

```
File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/home, referer: http://64.91.226.165/~captainj/backoffice/
```

What can I do, did you meet this kind of problem so far?
Thanks

AS YOU CAN SEE I AM ACCESSING THE DOMAIN THROUGH IP ADDRESS AS THE DNS IS NOT SET YET

UPDATE:

I just found out that this is happening only when I try to access the module through IP address. I have copied it on another server and accessed by domain name and it works. But I still need to get this work using IP address.

Comment: Did you try to access the file directly via browser?

Comment: yes I've tried and the same is happening.

Comment: so you're saying backoffice itself not working when accessing directly? Post the code and complete location of the files

Comment: what code you want me to post?

Comment: Have you set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://64.91.226.165/~captainj/backoffice/';` in your config file?

Comment: yes I've set this as base_url

Answer (score 0):

try removing the url bad part with `htaccess` removing also index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~captainj/backoffice/index.php/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```